# Cannot use Diplomat in database.yml on Rails with Fusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, fusion

I'm attempting to use https://github.com/WeAreFarmGeek/diplomat

As per their README instructions I have adjusted my database.yml like so:

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
production:
  adapter:            postgresql
  encoding:           unicode
  host:               <%= Diplomat::Service.get('postgres').Address %>
  database:           <%= Diplomat::Kv.get('project/db/name') %>
  pool:               5
  username:           <%= Diplomat::Kv.get('project/db/user') %>
  password:           <%= Diplomat::Kv.get('project/db/pass') %>
  port:               <%= Diplomat::Service.get('postgres').ServicePort %>
<% end %>
```

When running with `RAILS_ENV=production rails c`, I can connect to the database fine. However, when the app is started with passenger, it seems these values are blank and I get the error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (No connection pool with 'primary' found.)`

I assume that passenger is being clever with the database.yml?

My suspicion is that ERB templating for the database.yml does not really
work except for with ENV vars explicitly passed from the nginx configuration.

Comment: I'm not aware of Passenger doing anything special with the `database.yml`. Are you 100% sure that you've configured Passenger app env to production so that the correct database.yml parts would be active?

Comment: It works perfectly when the values are hardcoded strings directly in the file. App env is being parsed correctly. The only change I actually made was to move from hardcoded values to using Diplomat.

Comment: I've not even been able to access env vars set in /etc/environment. The only variables I've been able to access from database.yml are the ones set explicitly using passenger_env_var in my nginx config.